# Нужна ли нам метка [python-3.x]?

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Как мне кажется, вряд ли остались люди, которые используют версию Python ниже 3.x. Исходя из этого, я задумался над ненужностью метки [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), ведь у нас есть метка [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) и можно было бы использовать её для всех вопросов по поводу Python, а не делить его на версии. К тому же, как я сказал выше, вряд ли кто-то использует более старые версии.

Делая вывод, я предлагаю удалить метку [python-3.x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (и вообще, метки с другими версиями) и оставить только [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Возможно, данное предложение прозвучит слишком дерзко, но, всё же, прошу его рассмотреть.

Буду рад узнать мнение других членов сообщества, по поводу этого.

Comment: "вряд ли отсались люди, которые использую версию Python ниже 3.x". Зря так думаете.

Comment: Так поддержка Python 2.7 уже прекращена аж с начала года, честно сказать, я не думал, что кто-то останется и будет на нем писать

Comment: Фиксы выходить всё ещё будут.

Comment: @h4cktivist, в организациях полно вспомогательных скриптов, написанных на python 2.x и никто не собирается их вообще трогать (как говорится -- если работает, то не тронь)

Comment: Понял, всем спасибо

Comment: У меня весь мой колхозный продакшен на втором питоне, переписать руки не доходят :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> вряд ли отсались люди, которые использую версию Python ниже 3.x

Тоже самое говорили и говорят про Java, мол "кто нынче ещё использует 6 версию"? Ответ - энтерпрайз.

Миграция с Python 2 на Python 3 очень сложная для больших проектов. А если в проекте используются библиотеки/компоненты, которые написаны на 2.x и не предоставляют 3.x версию, то всё становится ещё хуже.

Да, если посмотреть статистику, то доля 2.x падает, но всё ещё довольна существенна. Поэтому я бы не стал пока удалять номерные метки.

Comment: можно вообще выпилить метку, _вряд ли отсались люди, которые использую Python_ (¬‿¬ )

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-in-2019. Верить этому опросу 6.5к разрабов или не верить - вам решать. Но я думаю, что это правда

Answer (score 8):

Даже если люди перестали что-то использовать (хотя про 2й питон я сильно сомневаюсь - вроде на него завязан cmake), то старые вопросы-то никуда не делись и вряд ли кто-то будет их все просматривать чтобы переставить метки в соответствии с новыми желаниями.

А ещё есть вопросы, которым не важна версия питона в принципе.

PS: Вот, [даже такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1108756/178988) до сих пор используют.